# Последовательный запуск видео

Tags: opencv

Перестал работать код.

```
imoprt cv2
import os
fds = sorted(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\123"))# Указываем папку в 
которой лежат видео
for img in fds:
if img.endswith(('.mp4')):
    print(img) # 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(img)
    while True:
         ret, frame = cap.read()
         if ret:
               сv2.imshow('image', cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480)))
         else:
              break
    cap.release()
```

Использовал его ранее все работало. В папке находиться несколько видео и они последовательно проигрываются. Теперь просто появляются названия файлов. Подскажите что могло пойти не так?

Comment: Что такое `v2.imshow` ?

Comment: @MBo,  поправил. Букву потерял.. Это библиотека openCV.

Comment: ОК. Не поможет ли waitkey после imshow?

Comment: @MBo, cv2.waitKey(1) использую, нет результата.

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) пишут, что после каждого кадру нужно системе дать время на показ `This function should be followed by cv::waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won't display the image.`

Comment: Если одно видео запускать, тоже так проиcходит? Что изменилось? может, теперь кодека mp4 нет или ещё что-то подобное?

Comment: @MBo, если указывать отдельно видео, то все работает. Также не видит любой другой формат видео. Хотя два дня назад все работало. Так же была ситуация что были 4 почти идентичных видео, три из них не запустилось, а четвертое видео запустилось....Не понимаю причины почему он его запускает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89707/discussion-between-andrey-zhuravlev-and-mbo).

Comment: Что отладка показывает про cap и ret?

Comment: @MBo, я использую ЮпитерНоутбук, и у меня здесь нет отладчика. (Ну или я о нем не знаю).По крайней мере ошибок в cap и ret не выдает.

Comment: У OpenCV вообще плохо с диагностикой, многие ошибки тихо прячутся. Ну print-то ведь работает, можно cap посмотреть и ret для нескольких кадров.

Comment: @MBo, cap - <VideoCapture 000001DE878177B0>, ret - False

Comment: т.е. надо разбираться, почему кадры не читаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня заработало, когда стал передавать в VideoCapture **полный путь** (с директорией), видео показываются последовательно

```
import os
import cv2

fds = sorted(os.listdir(r"D:\000\1\16-08-2013"))
for img in fds:
    if img.endswith(('.avi')):
        print(img) #
        nam = os.path.join(r"D:\000\1\16-08-2013", img)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(nam)
        while True:
             ret, frame = cap.read()
             if ret:
                   cv2.imshow('image', frame)
                   cv2.waitKey(2)
             else:
                  break
        cap.release()
```

Comment: и видео  последовательно загружается или только один файл?

Comment: Последовательно. Папка не текущая, поэтому одного имени не было достаточно.

Comment: Благодарю, заработало.